# How to Send Form Data i.e File with Form Data from Angular 5 to Web API

Tags: file-upload, parameters, angular6

I want to send formdata(File upload) along different other parameters from Angular to C# webAPI.

Web api:

```
[Route("PostTime")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTime(PostTimeObject _Model)
    {
        try
        {

            return Content(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotModified, "Unable to read values");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Content(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent , "Unable to read values");
        }
    }
```

PostTime is class :

```
    public class PostTimeObject
{
public string ClientID { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; 
}
```

Angular:

```
let selectedFile =<File> evt.target.files[0];
this.fdata.append('attachedFile',selectedFile,selectedFile.name)// fdata is FormData

P_Data.clientID : this.Form.control["Clientid"].value
P_Data.ClientName : this.Form.control["ClientName "].value

this.http.post("localhost/Times/PostTime",P_Data,{ headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" })}).subscribe((s)=>
    {
      console.log(s)
    })
```

receiving error in Browser:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type", url: "http://localhost:53265/Timesheet/PostTimeSheet", ok: false, …}
```